# RestartApplication is not getting called after Intune enrolment for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, adal, intune

As per Microsoft Intune Documentation.

> When an app receives MAM policies for the first time, it must restart to apply the required hooks. To notify the app that a restart needs to happen, the SDK provides a delegate method in IntuneMAMPolicyDelegate.h. [refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/developer/app-sdk-ios)

I have implemented the same in Xamarin.

```
var authResult = await adalHelper.Authenticate();

if(authResult != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authResult.AccessToken)){

var enrollmentDel = new EnrollmentDelegate(this);
IntuneMAMEnrollmentManager.Instance.Delegate = enrollmentDel;


IntuneMAMPolicyManager.Instance.Delegate = new EnrollmentPolicyDelegate();
                       IntuneMAMEnrollmentManager.Instance.RegisterAndEnrollAccount(authResult.UserInfo.DisplayableId.ToLower());
```

}

EnrollmentPolicyDelegate:

```
 public class EnrollmentPolicyDelegate : IntuneMAMPolicyDelegate
{
    public override bool RestartApplication
    {
        get
        {
            var returnedVal = base.RestartApplication;

            return returnedVal;
        }
    }
}
```

As per documentation, I am supposed to use this property to know when I need to restart the application

I need your help to figure that out. When and at stage, and where I use this property to decide. For me it never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the document of `restartApplication` in [IntuneMAMPolicyDelegate.h](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-ios/blob/master/Headers/IntuneMAMPolicyDelegate.h#L49), it says:

> This method is Called by the Intune SDK when the application needs to restart because
>   policy has been received for the first time, or if we're handling a
>   mam-ca remediation and are restarting as a part of a SW because we
>   need to remove an existing user.

In my understanding, the method is managered by `Intune SDK` and you just need to return `ture/false` to determine who should handle the restart.(That means you don't have to use this property to decide)

- Returns **TRUE** if the host application will restart `on its own`.
- Returns **FALSE** if the host application wants the `Intune SDK` to handle
  the restart

And I checked some samples, they return `false` to let the `Intune SDK` to handle the restart. You can see the source code in [Chatr-Sample-Intune-iOS-App](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/Chatr-Sample-Intune-iOS-App/blob/master/chatr/PolicyDelegate.swift#L65) and [Wagr-Sample-Intune-iOS-App](https://github.com/microsoft/Wagr-Sample-Intune-iOS-App/blob/master/ECHackDemoApp/ECHackDemoApp/ReportsViewController.m#L208).

Comment: Kindly correct me if I understood you not well enough: You are saying when you tested those sample, restartApplication() method was getting called by SDK?

Comment: Yes, I tested the Wagr-Sample-Intune-iOS-App.